# got an error gawk: symbol lookup error: gawk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub

Tags: 16.04, compiling, paths

all, I get an error that indicates that 
*gawk: symbol lookup error: gawk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub* when I want to compile a simulation [from www.yonch.com/wireless](http://www.yonch.com/wireless).

This error was occurred when I type

```
 /wireless/release$ CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include -DNDEBUG" CXXFLAGS="-03" ../configure --prefix=$HOME
```

the result is

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
gawk: symbol lookup error: gawk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub
config.status: error: could not create Makefile
```

I'm a new user with Ubuntu, and I don't know how to fix it, can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: I do not know the package which you are trying to compile, but [linked page](http://www.yonch.com/wireless) contains dependencies and build instruction. Try to follow them step by step. It may differ in small, because it was written for 12.04 (EOL now).

Comment: this is correct .. i was reading up on it .. the error has to do with the environment settings .. so following step by step should fix your issue

Comment: Not really a solution, but you might try adding `AWK="/usr/bin/mawk"` to the list of variable-value pairs before `./configure`

Comment: Thank you for reply. It's my first time to use ubuntu to do the simulation. And I'm following the tutorial step by step, but many problems occur. This is the latest one... Some people say maybe it is because the PATH problem like that

Comment: awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub
A work-around is to manually execute unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH afterwards before installing the cross-compiler.

Comment: I'm confused - as far as I can see, you shouldn't need to mess with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`or install a cross-compiler.

Comment: yes, you're right, it's my mistake, and I fix it now. Thank you very much for reply.