# an error about awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub

Tags: 16.04, make

It's my first time using Ubuntu. So, I met with too many problems to solve. Until now I solved most of them, but I face a problem like this:

[image]

For example, it told me the make version is too low in my computer. But the version I checked is higher than that.

Here is the problem:
My tutorial website is http://www.yonch.com/wireless. Everything is fine before the *Setting up the environment* part in the tutorial website, and I have also set up my environment as it said (maybe here is the problem).

Then, I go on to follow the instructions under the *Checking installation* part of the tutorial website, but nothing other than an error occured.

[image]

After that, I tried to apply a potential answer that types the following commands to fix the error:

1. `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6`;
2. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`;
3. `sudo apt-get update`;
4. `sudo apt-get upgrade`;
5. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`;

After the 5 steps, the former error is not fixed, but a new error occured.

[image]

Then I don't know how to recover it or fix it. Please help me.

Comment: Give us some background here please - `petalinux` is some kind of embedded toolchain, isn't it? what exactly are you trying to do? what was the sequence of operations/commands that led up to this error?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. You are a really nice person. In fact, I'm following a tutorial step bu step to deploy simulation environment. All commands are passed and I think it's finished. But no. When testing the python, I got an error. I add the screen shot of the error in the question.

Comment: And I searched how to fix it, then someone says the following commands may help, then I follow it. The commands are : 1. sudo apt-get install libstdc++6  2.  sudo add-apt-respository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test  3.  sudo apt-get update  4. sudo-apt-get upgrade  5. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  Then the errors in my questions occur. I feel hopeless because I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: anyone can help me? I really need help.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial that you are following? or [edit] your question to summarize the steps

Comment: yes, I edit my question to describe how my problems occur, please help me fix it. PLEASE

Comment: I can understand what you are trying to achieve. Does current question connected with [previous one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984774/got-an-error-gawk-symbol-lookup-error-gawk-undefined-symbol-mpfr-z-sub)? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/984841/edit)  with concrete target and step by step trial-and-error protocol.